# Freezing animation when switching activities

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, kotlin

Actually I have two Activity , my SplashScreen (loads data from Webservice etc..) and my MainActivity

The problem is here : When my Splashscreen end loading data and start to make transition to go to MainActivity, the snowfall animation litteraly stop in the middle of the screen for 1 - 1.5seconds then make transition to MainActivty !

The snowfall animation seems to freeze , it happens too with another animation used in my SplashScreen ( element rotation )

When my Splashscreen ended to loads data , it calls :

```
 startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
 finish()
```

And then the transition works , my MainActivity appears

Can you tell me what to do please because it looks very bad.

This freeze appears on a real phone (Nokia 6) and on android studio emulator, and I'm launching it in Debug mode

**EDIT : Here is a part of my SplashScreen , nothing special , I'm doing animations then I call goHome() method**

```
class WelcomeScreen : Activity()
{
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    //Remove title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

    //Remove notification bar
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)

    // Start Background Animation
   AnimationManager.performRotationAnimation(this, R.id.sun_2)

   goHome()
}

    fun goHome()
   {
      startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
      finish()
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey Manu , Its better for users if you provide a little more info about your code, if possible please post your Splash Screen code.

Comment: @Manish Hello, I did , I can't post all of my SplashScreen code because it's almost 200 lines and I don't think that it's important in this case to have all , because even if I desactivate this code , my animation still freeze

Answer (score 0):

Use this for activity animation, it may help you for activity switch animation

```
startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_popup_enter,R.anim.abc_popup_exit)
```